# Print string starting with NUL in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have a string which starts with the character `\0` - it's by design and I know its actual length.

How can I print its representation using escapes like `"\0foo\0bar\0"`, if I know its length?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you should be able to print it as an array:

`print *str@length`

Comment: @gamen: do not confuse NUL with NULL. The former is a character, the later is a pointer.

Comment: @Flavius: Thanks; careless usage on my side. "Null character" is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDB printf command.

You just need to print the char *, incremented by one, so you don't have the NULL character.

If you have the following code:

```
int main( void )
{
    char * s1 = "abcd";
    char * s2 = "\0abcd";
    return 0;
}
```

Compile your program with:

```
gcc -Wall -g -o test test.c
```

Then run GDB:

```
gdb test
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000f04: file test.c, line 3.
(gdb) si
1       char * s1 = "abcd";
(gdb) si
2       char * s2 = "\0abcd";
(gdb) printf "%s", s1
abcd
(gdb) printf "%s", s2+1
abcd
```